# Android Menu item is displayed in overflow area even with app:showAsAction always

Tags: android

I am using MainActivity to extend Activity class. Project is using minimum API as 11. When I am inflating Menu Items, it always gets displayed in overflow.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
....
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the Menu Items
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
    return true;
}
```

[menu_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqftK.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">
 <item android:id="@+id/attach"
    android:title="Attachment"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Please don't put the screenshots of code

Comment: post menu_main.xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MainActivity extends Activity not AppcompatActivity and you are using android: Theme.Holo.Light native theme so, can u just replace

app:showAsAction="always" with android:showAsAction="always"

and try, like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">
 <item android:id="@+id/attach"
    android:title="Attachment"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks. It was somwhow referring to old AppcompatActivity dependency.

Comment: this answer doest work when i extend Activity and use android:showAsAction="always" . this answer is wrong@Biswajitghosh

Comment: @AmitVaghela which theme you r using?

Comment: parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"

Comment: @AmitVaghela he is using android:Theme.Holo.Light that's the difference. I hope you get it?:)

Comment: this is a overflow or underflow issue not a theme issue

Comment: @AmitVaghela As I know it depends on the Theme of the application OP using the native android:Theme.Holo.Light theme and you are using support theme that makes difference I guess?

Comment: @AmitVaghela it might help https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html and https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html

Comment: nop, something is wrong. this issue can be solved using my answer also

Comment: @AmitVaghela okay can u change your theme to android:Theme.Holo.Light  and try once?

Comment: @AmitVaghela I have tried with your answer. It's showing as overflow menu . I can share the screenshot if u want

Comment: got it but it is showing me error in showAsAction using same case

Comment: @AmitVaghela u need to change the xmlns I guess in menu

Comment: using that only it gives warning in menu file

Comment: @AmitVaghela its a warning right. We need to use Appcompat. It starts from changing the Theme itself

Comment: @AmitVaghela so how can we conclude this long conversation? :D Are u agree with the answer?

Comment: @AmitVaghela okay both are correct! :D depends on the scenario

Comment: dont you think that is wrong ?

Comment: @AmitVaghela if it's wrong my answer won't work for the OP :D

Answer (score 0):

Set it as showAsAction="always"

Comment: Still no helping..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

to show in overflow :

```
yourapp:showAsAction="always"
```

to show underflow

```
yourapp:showAsAction="never"
```

---

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/attach"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_hardware_keyboard_arrow_left"
        android:title="Attachment"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

check this [menu resource doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)

Comment: try my updated answer and tell me if you have any issues@Biswajit ghosh

Comment: HI Amit thanks for your answer . But It will work only if your project has a dependency on AppCompat. Since i deleted Appcompat dependency so i had to use android:showAsAction instead of a custom namespace like yourapp: .